# Resizing special fonts

Tags: winforms, controls

I am resizing my controls and texts at runtime based on screen resolution using
the routine below.
This is working fine except for fonts such as "Wingdings 3".
"Wingdings 3" is bringing the actual character "Å" instead of the "left arrow".
Any ideas why?

```
public void ResizeControls(Control objCtl)
    {
        foreach (Control cChildren in objCtl.Controls)
        {
            if (cChildren.HasChildren)
            {
                ResizeControls(cChildren);
            }
            else
            {
                cChildren.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * cChildren.Width / DesignWidth, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * cChildren.Height / DesignHeight);
                cChildren.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * cChildren.Left / DesignWidth, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * cChildren.Top / DesignHeight);

                if ((cChildren.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Label) | (cChildren.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Button))))
                    cChildren.Font = new Font(cChildren.Font.FontFamily.Name, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * cChildren.Font.Size / DesignHeight, cChildren.Font.Style, cChildren.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));    // <-- HERE RESIZING A CONTROLS FONT PROPERTY 
            }
        }
        objCtl.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * objCtl.Width / DesignWidth, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * objCtl.Height / DesignHeight);
        objCtl.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * objCtl.Left / DesignWidth, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * objCtl.Top / DesignHeight);

        if ((objCtl.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Label)) | (objCtl.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Button)))
            objCtl.Font = new Font(objCtl.Font.FontFamily, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * objCtl.Font.Size / DesignHeight, objCtl.Font.Style, objCtl.Font.Unit, ((byte)(0)));  // <-- HERE RESIZING A CONTROLS FONT PROPERTY 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  I was setting the GDI character set to 0 instead of copying the fonts original GDI character set.

```
"objCtl.Font.GdiCharSet"
```